# Install youtube plugin in CKEditor with a custom toolbar

Tags: youtube, ckeditor

I want to install the [youtube plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/youtube) of CKEditor.
No problem to install it, it works good.

But I want also to configure my own toolbar. For example :

```
<div id="editable" contenteditable="true" class="ckeditor">
  my data
</div>
<script>
  // Turn off automatic editor creation first.
  CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;

  CKEDITOR.inline( 'editable', {
    toolbar: [
      { name: 'insert', items: [ 'Link', 'Unlink', 'Image', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar', 'youtubePlugin' ] },

    ]
} );
</script>
```

But the youtube icon does not display. I have tried other name like 'youtube', 'Youtube', nothing is working.
And I don't find other name of plugin on the source code.

Do you know how to that ?

Thanks.

Eric

Comment: does your config.js consist of something like:
config.extraPlugins = 'youtube';
?

Comment: yes, it does. And I have tried to add the plugin in the toolbar with the keywords youtubePlugin, youtube, Youtube, it does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I have found the problem. My holidays were beneficts :)

I have to set the good name of the plugin. Here it is "Youtube" and not "youtube".
And it works good now for all plugins.

Eric